# ResteasyProviderFactory exception in Glassfish

Tags: java, rest, httpclient, resteasy

I'm having some trouble invoking a RESTful webservice using the Client Framework provided by RESTEasy. When I try to register the ResteasyProviderFactory I got a ClassCastException and nothing more works.

Here's the code:

```
    RegisterBuiltin.register(ResteasyProviderFactory.getInstance());
    LifeGoalClient leClient = ProxyFactory.create(LifeGoalClient.class, "http://localhost:8080/TutorFinanceiro");
    List<LifeGoal> lifeGoals = leClient.getLifeGoals();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, lifeGoals);
    return lifeGoals;
```

And the exception:

```
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.jersey.server.impl.provider.RuntimeDelegateImpl cannot be cast to org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory
```

I'm using Glassfish 3.0.1 and Resteasy 2.2.1.

I searched through the web but found no solution or no relevant info in respect to this.
If anyone have a solution or an alternative way of doing this, please help me!

Thanks in advance

Comment: i take a lot of researchs about that and i didnt found anything useless, just workaround that doesnt work as well. I think that switch Jersey over RestEasy in this case is the better choice.

Answer (score 5):

I did force resteasy over jersey in glassfish by adding a file named javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate in the class path at "META-INF/services", wich contain only the following line : 
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory

However, for me, all seemed to work fine until I try to use resteasy-cdi.  Adding that last artifact to my dependencies and configuring the required context-param did dig up the same classcast problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by conflicting jax-rs implementation - jersey and resteasy.
In order to prevent the error above, you can add

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.use.deployment.sensitive.factory</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

in your web.xml.

By doing so, resteasy will choose instance of ResteasyProviderFactory.